# Conjecture concerning involutions in a unitary braided fusion category/Grothendieck ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

Despite the categorical setup, a solution to this question may require no categorical tools (see Conjecture 2).

Let $\mathcal C$ be a unitary braided fusion category, $I$ be its set of isomorphism classes of simple objects, and $K(\mathcal C)$ be the Grothendieck ring. Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $I$ *generated* by $u\sim v$ if there exist some $k \geq 2$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_k\in I$ such that $x_1\otimes \cdots \otimes x_k \cong u \oplus v \oplus \cdots$ I'll denote duals by $a^*$ etc. I'd like to know if the following is true.

**Conjecture 1**. Let $t:I \rightarrow I$ be any involutive set map that induces an involutive ring automorphism $K(\mathcal C) \rightarrow K(\mathcal C)$. Take any $a\in I$ such that $t.a \sim a^*$. Then there exist $a'\sim a$ and $c\in I$ such that $a'\otimes t.a' \cong c\oplus\cdots$ (i.e. $N_{a',t.a'}^c\neq 0$) and $t.c=c$.

My sense is that we don't need the full-fledged unitary braided fusion category here, but only the fusion rules. Thus let me give a purely algebraic version, which, if true, would imply Conjecture 1:

**Conjecture 2.** Let $I$ be a finite set. Let $(K(\mathcal C),\oplus,\otimes,\boldsymbol 1)$ be a commutative unital ring that as an abelian group is freely generated by $I$, such that $\forall x, y\in I$, $x\otimes y=a_1\oplus\cdots \oplus a_k$ for some $a_1, \ldots, a_k\in I$. Let $\ast: I \rightarrow I$ be an involutive set map inducing a ring automorphism $K(\mathcal C) \rightarrow K(\mathcal C)$, and assume that $\forall x\in I$, $x^*$ is the unique element of $I$ such that $x\otimes x^* = \boldsymbol 1 \oplus \cdots$ Let $t:I\rightarrow I$ be another involutive set map inducing a ring automorphism $K(\mathcal C) \rightarrow K(\mathcal C)$. Take any $a\in I$ such that $t.a \sim a^*$. Then there exist $a'\sim a$ and $c\in I$ such that $a'\otimes t.a' = c\oplus\cdots$ and $t.c=c$.

I don't see why the conjectures must hold, but haven't found a conterexample either. I'm willing to make additional assumptions if necessary: e.g., that the "fusion products" (i.e. the $a_i$'s) of two simple objects are all distinct.

Thank you in advance!

---

As an example, consider $Rep(D_{2n})$, the finite dimensional representations of the dihedral group $D_{2n}=\langle a,x|a^n=x^2=1,xax=a^{-1}\rangle$, with $n=6,10,14,...$ The irreps are
\begin{eqnarray}
R_{++}(a)=1, &&R_{++}(x)=1,\\
R_{+-}(a)=1, &&R_{+-}(x)=-1,\\
R_{-+}(a)=-1, &&R_{-+}(x) = 1,\\
R_{--}(a)=-1, &&R_{--}(x)=-1,\\
R_k(a)=\begin{bmatrix}e^{2\pi i k/n} & 0\\0 & e^{-2\pi i k/n} \end{bmatrix}, &&R_k(x)=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},
\end{eqnarray}
where $1\leq k \leq \frac{n}{2}-1$. The "fusion rules" are
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\underline{~~~~~~~~~~|~~ R_{++} ~~~~~~ R_{+-} ~~~~~~ R_{-+} ~~~~~~ R_{--} ~~~~~~ R_l} \\
&&R_{++}~~|~~ R_{++} ~~~~~~ R_{+-} ~~~~~~ R_{-+} ~~~~~~ R_{--} ~~~~~~ R_l \\
&&R_{+-}~~|~~ R_{+-} ~~~~~~ R_{++} ~~~~~~ R_{--} ~~~~~~ R_{-+} ~~~~~~ R_l\\
&&R_{-+}~~|~~ R_{-+} ~~~~~~ R_{--} ~~~~~~ R_{++} ~~~~~~ R_{+-} ~~~~~~ R_{\frac n2-l}\\
&&R_{--}~~|~~ R_{--} ~~~~~~ R_{-+} ~~~~~~ R_{+-} ~~~~~~ R_{++} ~~~~~~ R_{\frac n2-l}\\
&&R_k~~~~~|~~ R_k ~~~~~~~~~ R_k ~~~~~~~~~ R_{\frac n2-k} ~~~~ R_{\frac n2-k} ~~~~ R_{k+l}\oplus R_{|k-l|}
\end{eqnarray}
where $R_0:=R_{++}\oplus R_{+-}$, $R_{\frac n2}:=R_{-+}\oplus R_{--}$, and $R_{n-k}\cong R_{k}$. So $R_{++}$ serves as $\boldsymbol 1$ and every simple object is its own dual.

We have two equivalence classes: $R_{++}\sim R_{+-} \sim R_{2k}$ and $R_{-+}\sim R_{--} \sim R_{2k+1}$. Let $a$ be as in Conjecture 2. Assume $a$ is in the second equivalence class, for otherwise we can take $a'=c=R_{++}$ and be done. Note that $t$ must leave $R_{++}$ and $R_{+-}$ invariant. On the other hand, $t$ must either leave $R_{-+}$, $R_{--}$ invariant or swap them. In the former case, $R_{-+}\otimes t.R_{-+} = R_{-+}\otimes R_{-+} = R_{++}$, so we can take $a'=R_{-+}, c=R_{++}$ and be done. In the latter case, $R_{-+}\otimes t.R_{-+} = R_{-+}\otimes R_{--} = R_{+-}$, so we can take $a'=R_{-+}, c=R_{+-}$ and be done.